# Find the probability that one will guess the correct password in the first attempt

Tags: probability

An 8 character password is randomly generated, determine the possibility that one will guess the correct password in the first attempt.

Restrictions:
All characters are in upper case letters, distinct and in alphabetical order

I only know the probability for char in upper case =  $$ 1/26^8 $$ &
probability for char in upper case and distinct = $$ 1/26 * 1/25 * 1/24 * 1/23 * 1/22 * 1/21 * 1/20 * 1/19 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
If the characters are all distinct, there is only *one* ordering that is alphabetical.

Comment: so the answer is 1/26C8 ?

Comment: @BEX Yes it is.

Comment: @BEX Correct! :)